# Want to find the issues

Tags: mysql

Assuming there's no syntax error and the column names and table names are correct, what's wrong with the MySQL query below?

(FOR EVERY USER WE HAVE, this is supposed to return the number of messages they sent)

```
select
u.user_id
, sum(case when um.message_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_messages_sent
from users u
left join users_messages um
  on um.user_id = u.user_id
where um.status = 'sent'
group by
u.user_id
;
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? What is your question exactly

Comment: Run EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS; I'll leave you to decide whether that result conforms with your definition of 'wrong'

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you expect to see users with no sent messages and a message count of 0, but you are not seeing them?  This is because you include `WHERE um.status = 'sent'` and this eliminates those records from the result set before the aggregation is performed.

There are a number of solutions to the problem.  Assuming Klaus, in the comment below, states that you'll get the effect you want by moving the condition into the JOIN clause.  You can also do `WHERE um.status = 'sent' or um.message_id IS NULL` (assuming `message_id` is declared NOT NULL) or `LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM user_messages WHERE status = 'sent') AS um` in the FROM clause.